# The best solution to keep files in database (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know what will be the best way to save binary files 'in database'.
Of course they will be on the disk as files, but i need some 'link' to them in the DB.
Any great solutions?

Comment: If they'll be on the disk anyway, why duplicate them in DB? You can just keep path in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to attach a file to a model.

Say you have a mortgage that has a document

```
class Mortgage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :document
end
```

Later:

```
mortgage = Mortgage.find(params[:id])
document = mortgage.document
```

Paperclip is usually used with images, but works with all types of files. You can easily store on s3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything against mongodb and gridfs, there's an example here http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/